# htmlspecialchars() when print view

Tags: php, laravel

I get the error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

When print the view get the error, I don't understand what is wrong in my code. I have print and object? How could solve it?

This is my controller:

```
    foreach($asesorias as $asesoria)
    {
        $asesoriasWithNames = Array
        (
            'comunidad' => Comunidad::getNameComunidad($asesoria->comunidad_id),
            'provincia' => Provincia::getProvinciaName($asesoria->provincia_id),
            'municipio' => Municipio::getMunicipioName($asesoria->municipio_id),
            'place' => $asesoria->place,
            'date' => $asesoria->date,
            'time' => $asesoria->time,
        );            
    }
    //dd($asesoriasWithNames);
    return view('procesar',compact('marker','asesoriasWithNames'));
```

This is my view:

```
       @foreach($asesoriasWithNames as $key => $value)
        @if($loop->index % 4 == 0)
            <div class="card-deck">
        @endif
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <img src="/adminlte/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">

                <p class="card-text">
                    <strong>$key: </strong>{{ $value }}<br>
                <p class="card-text text-center" style="position:absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Reservar</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if($loop->iteration % 4 == 0)
            </div>
        @endif

    @endforeach
```

This is my dd() print:

```
 array:6 [▼
  "comunidad" => {#432 ▼
    +"comunidad": "Cantabria"
  }
  "provincia" => {#441 ▼
    +"provincia": "Cantabria"
  }
  "municipio" => {#440 ▼
    +"municipio": "Arredondo"
  }
  "place" => "Centro Comercial Valle Real Calle Alday, S/N, Maliaño"
  "date" => "2020-01-29"
  "time" => "09:00:00"
]
```

Comment: In your first 3 iterations of `$key => $value`, you can't print `$value`, since it is an Object. You'll need to add some logic in your loop to print `{{ $value->comunidad }}`, `{{ $value->provincia }}` and `{{ $value->municipio }}`. Maybe check for `get_class($value)`, or something else.

Comment: how could I get only string instead and object, I have try with this but returns null:     public static function getNameComunidad($id)
    {
        $name = DB::table('comunidades')
                            ->where('id', '=', $id)               
                            ->value('comunidad');
    }

Comment: `$name = DB::table('comunidades')->where('id', '=', $id)->first()->comunidad`. I haven't seen the `->value()` call before, but `first()->{attribute}` should work for you.

Comment: thanks, but I get null value. I don't now why. I tested $name = DB::table('comunidades')->where('id', '=', $id)->first()->comunidad

Comment: That can still be `null`. `->first()` does not guarantee a value is returned. Post the contents of the 3 functions into your question; might help us debug.

Comment: solved. I had not written the "return" word, due to some tests.

Comment: Ah yeah, that would do it. If you omit a `return` statement from a function, assigning a variable to it will result in `null`. Glad you got it working though! Feel free to post a self-answer and accept it (when the system allows you) to properly close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function to return a string only and not an object

**Before:**

```
public static function getNameComunidad($id)
{
    return DB::table('comunidades')
                        ->where('id', '=', $id)               
                        ->first();
}
```

**Changed**:

```
public static function getNameComunidad($id)
{
    return DB::table('comunidades')
                        ->where('id', '=', $id)               
                        ->first()->comunidad;
}
```